# how just fetch 2 entity that related by some other entity to each other in Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I think my question title is not clear enough so I place an example(symfony2 & Doctrine2):

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery(
            'SELECT j, jp, po, p from MjJobBundle:Job j'
            . ' LEFT JOIN j.jobPackage jp'
            . ' JOIN jp.packageOrder po'
            . ' JOIN po.package p');
```

If I just want Job and Package entity I must retrieve all four entities is there any simple solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Do JOINS is the solutions. If you just want Job and Package entities, do not select the other entities:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery(
        'SELECT j, p from MjJobBundle:Job j'
        . ' LEFT JOIN j.jobPackage jp'
        . ' JOIN jp.packageOrder po'
        . ' JOIN po.package p');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. that's the problem, if i dont select other entities I cannot access package directly. I can acces Package name attr in twig like this: job.jobPackage.packageOrder.package.name